# Adding Context Menu to App Launcher - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension, and I am trying to add a "Logout" Context menu in the App Launcher.

Here is my code:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
"title": "Logout",
"type": 'normal',
"contexts": ["launcher"],
"onclick" : function clickHandler(){ alert("Logout");}
});
```

But the Problem is that it does not add the menu any where. However when I pass following array to "contexts" `["page", "selection", "image", "link"]`  it displays the menu at all the places expected.

I am following the API guide published by Google:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus

**All I want is to display the menu when I right-click the launcher only**

Kindly Guide me on what I am doing wrong. Thanks

*******************************Image for more clarity*******************************

[image]

You see the extension I have highlighted. When I right click, a menu appears. I want to be able to add more items on that menu.

Comment: As a comment, it was requested as a feature a long time ago, but it was completely ignored by the Chromium team: https://crbug.com/56980

Comment: Thanks @Xan for this useful piece of information. I'll look into it more and see if I can come up with a good solution

Comment: Maybe I could submit a new feature request for that.

Answer (score 1):

The button you have in your screenshot is an extension browserAction which does not **yet** support contextMenus. App launchers are [described here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/launcher). An apps and extensions are different things and support different Chrome APIs.

In an extension you might use the [options page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options) to provide logout functionality.

In a [few months](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+FrancoisBeaufort/posts/e5YmJj5VNSR) there is a `browser_action` context coming out for contextMenuse.

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs you linked to.

> The 'launcher' context is **only supported by apps** and is used to add menu items to the context menu that appears when clicking on the app icon in the launcher/taskbar/dock/etc.

Comment: can you elaborate more please. I need the menu item when I right click the app button on the browser tray. Do you think if this is something possible?

Comment: Can you post your manifest.json file? It will help to see what you are saying.

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with manifest. Google developers provide an API to do that. All we need to do is find a solution in that.

Comment: @TalhaMasood No, they don't provide an API for browser action context menus. See my comment on the question.